# Dividing non-equal dataframes based on a group condition

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, with a similar strucure:

```
df_I <- structure(list(year = c("2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", 
"2006", "2006", "2006", "2006"), code = c(0, 1110, 
1120, 1130, 1220, 1230, 1310, 1320, 1330), `1` = c(1L, 
8L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L), `2` = c(0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L), `3` = c(4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 
0L, 0L, 3L), `4` = c(4L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L), 
    totaal = c(11, 26, 3, 7, 1, 9, 7, 7, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 9 × 7
  year   code   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4` totaal
  <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>
1 2006      0     1     0     4     4     11
2 2006   1110     8    10     2     6     26
3 2006   1120     2     0     1     0      3
4 2006   1130     2     0     2     3      7
5 2006   1220     0     0     0     1      1
6 2006   1230     2     2     4     3      9
7 2006   1310     0     1     0     0      7
8 2006   1320     1     3     0     0      7
9 2006   1330     0     1     3     3      6

df_II <- structure(list(year = c("2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", 
"2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006"), code = c(0, 1110, 
1120, 1130, 1210, 1220, 1230, 1310, 1320, 1330), `1` = c(15806L, 
655L, 105L, 328L, 138L, 452L, 445L, 471L, 672L, 615L), `2` = c(9681L, 
337L, 68L, 215L, 97L, 357L, 366L, 245L, 440L, 360L), `3` = c(10457L, 
221L, 40L, 123L, 65L, 325L, 322L, 151L, 352L, 332L), `4` = c(7109L, 
128L, 5L, 64L, 56L, 256L, 240L, 83L, 274L, 192L), totaal = c(43053, 
1341, 218, 730, 356, 1390, 1373, 950, 1738, 1499)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 10 × 7
   year   code   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4` totaal
   <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>
 1 2006      0 15806  9681 10457  7109  43053
 2 2006   1110   655   337   221   128   1341
 3 2006   1120   105    68    40     5    218
 4 2006   1130   328   215   123    64    730
 5 2006   1210   138    97    65    56    356
 6 2006   1220   452   357   325   256   1390
 7 2006   1230   445   366   322   240   1373
 8 2006   1310   471   245   151    83    950
 9 2006   1320   672   440   352   274   1738
10 2006   1330   615   360   332   192   1499
```

I would like to create a new data.frame `df_out`, which divides `df_I` by `df_II`, for columns `1,2,3,4, totaal` by `year` and `code`. The issue is that not every `code` is available for each year.

What is the best way to divide this unequal dataframe?

Desired outcome:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 7
   year       code   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4` totaal
   <chr>     <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>
 1 2006       0 1 /15806 0/9681 4/10457  4/7109  11/43053
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `complete` to make the number of rows between the two data frames equal, and then do the division:

```r
library(tidyr)
df_I %<>% 
  complete(code = df_II$code) %>% 
  fill(year) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)

cbind(df_I[c(1, 2)], df_I[-c(1, 2)] / df_II[-c(1, 2)])
```

```r
    code year        `1`     `2`      `3`      `4`   totaal
   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     0 2006  0.0000633 0       0.000383 0.000563 0.000255
 2  1110 2006  0.0122    0.0297  0.00905  0.0469   0.0194  
 3  1120 2006  0.0190    0       0.025    0        0.0138  
 4  1130 2006  0.00610   0       0.0163   0.0469   0.00959 
 5  1210 2006  0         0       0        0        0       
 6  1220 2006  0         0       0        0.00391  0.000719
 7  1230 2006  0.00449   0.00546 0.0124   0.0125   0.00655 
 8  1310 2006  0         0.00408 0        0        0.00737 
 9  1320 2006  0.00149   0.00682 0        0        0.00403 
10  1330 2006  0         0.00278 0.00904  0.0156   0.00400
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am trying to figure out how the `fill` function works here. In the actual data, there are many more years (up to 2020). How should I adapt the code for this?

Comment: Depends on how your data is structured, but since the `fill` argument is rather limited in `complete`, you could use `fill(year)` instead. See edit

Comment: @Tom Why not provide a _minimal_ example that better captures the complexity of your real data, e.g. two years? The toy data could well be _smaller overall_ though, e.g. fewer rows per year, fewer columns, and still capture the core issue. Perhaps something like `d1 = data.frame(year = rep(1:2, each = 3), code = letters[1:6], v1 = 11:16, v2 = 10:15)`;  `d2 = data.frame(year = rep(1:2, each = 3), code = c("b", "c", "d", "c", "d", "e"), v1 = 3:8, v2 = 1:6)`. Also, does df2 always contain the complete set of 'code' (seems like an assumption in this answer)? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could `subset` the second data frame using `%in%`, assuming both code columns are properly ordered.

```
cols <- as.character(1:4)
cbind(df_I[setdiff(names(df_I), cols)], df_I[cols] / subset(df_II, code %in% df_I$code, cols))
#   year code totaal            1           2            3           4
# 1 2006    0     11 6.326711e-05 0.000000000 0.0003825189 0.000562667
# 2 2006 1110     26 1.221374e-02 0.029673591 0.0090497738 0.046875000
# 3 2006 1120      3 1.904762e-02 0.000000000 0.0250000000 0.000000000
# 4 2006 1130      7 6.097561e-03 0.000000000 0.0162601626 0.046875000
# 5 2006 1220      1 0.000000e+00 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.003906250
# 6 2006 1230      9 4.494382e-03 0.005464481 0.0124223602 0.012500000
# 7 2006 1310      7 0.000000e+00 0.004081633 0.0000000000 0.000000000
# 8 2006 1320      7 1.488095e-03 0.006818182 0.0000000000 0.000000000
# 9 2006 1330      6 0.000000e+00 0.002777778 0.0090361446 0.015625000
```